# Rotating an image back to it's original state

Tags: java, image, image-processing, trigonometry, image-rotation

I have a program that needs to take in a photo taken by an iphone (or any kind of decent camera) of a 7x10 grid with a thick black boarder around the edges. This image can be received rotated to the right or to the left (there's no need to worry about skew). I have an image of the grid in its original state already, but I need to get the picture that I'm taking in and rotate it to its "perfect/original" state.

**Idea 1: Performance Hog/Bad Results**

Threshold the picture that I receive and the perfect grid Image I already have. Compare each pixel for 0 rotation, get a total score, and save it. Do do this rotating the image of increments by 1 to 359. The lowest score is the rotation we need to get the picture back to its original state.

**Idea 2: Still Unsure How To Go About Doing This**

Threshold the picture that I receive and the perfect grid Image I already have. Draw a a line through the center of the picture vertically and horizontally. Find the rotation based on the black pixel count that the vertical and horizontal line passed through. This would require some sort of Trigonometry that I'm not to great with understanding.

Does anyone have any other ideas for getting this working?

Any help for pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Trig is easy... just remember SOHCAHTOA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but if I only know the hypotenuse and the obvious 90 degree angle, how do I figure out the other two distances to find theta (the degrees of rotation to get back to the original state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of drawing one horizontal and one vertical line, draw instead two horizontal lines (say, each at a third of the picture). Only look at the left halves of these lines and calculate how many black pixels there are on the path of each (`a1` and `a2`). You also have to keep track of the distance between the two red lines, so the number of pixels `d`.

[image: Diagram of the problem, as I understand it]

Using this notation in the figure above, your desired angle is:

`alpha=atan2((a2-a1),d)`

and a counterclockwise rotation by `alpha` will bring the white portion of the picture into proper alignment.

Comment: I just realized I forgot to mention that this method is prone to noise. The errors go down as `d` increases, but if you pick `d` too large the method won't work at all (the red lines won't intersect the correct sides). Also, parts of the picture could have black pixels that throw your measurement off. As a second step, you could repeat this procedure several times for different values of `d` and for the four different sides of your image, then average the measurements, with an optional step of throwing out outliers.